# Make App Store Promo Codes Scannable Like Starbucks Does?

Tags: app-store, promotions

My app is in review and I'm trying to make some promo codes that are scannable so I can print them on cards similar to the "app pick of the week" by starbucks. They put the app promo code in a box and it is scannable using the app store app. I gave this a shot and it didn't work. Is this due to apple not allowing others to use this tech or is my image just the wrong size?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this to work using [Ayuthaya](http://www.findmyfont.com/index.php/fonts/font-preview?fset=Mac-OS-Fonts&ffam=&fid=013969851c3b451b1d2e7decff91b3ee) as the typeface. I also just made sure the type and box size were similar. Hope this helps!

Comment: Ayuthaya worked for me also. I found that I could iterate rapidly by using a valid code in a photoshop mockup, and scanning my screen directly. The padding on the box and relative size/stroke of the box mattered a great deal, so being able to test directly on my screen saved a ton of paper and time spent printing.